# Does CSS class name length affect browser performance?

Tags: html, css, performance, browser

Example: Gmail.

From all the DOM elements, ~2000 have at least one CSS class and there are a total of ~500 distinct CSS class names on the page. Gmail uses closure-stylesheets to minify/uglify their CSS class names. Does this step increase performance in the browser. I'm thinking about parsing/evaluating the HTML/CSS code, selector-matching, etc.

Example of uglified class name: "aBc"
Example of original class name: "tooblar__button--disabled"

Comment: apart from minor improvements in download size? I don't think it matters much.

Comment: There are larger gains to be found elsewhere, sprites comes to mind for one. Although, I suppose if you're resorting to smaller class names, you've exhausted every *other* avenue of optimisation..?

Comment: Longer names increase download times, yes, but also memory footprint. I imagine there are optimizations against that as well, or if, say, you use up to X number of characters, it does not matter because they allocate so and so bytes in the memory for each class.

Comment: I suspect GMail does that because they have a lot of elements and they tend to use very descriptive names (as they should). Longer names can indeed take more memory, eventually. But the real primary reason is probably to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Fewer bytes is fewer bytes. The chances of it being a *significant* factor are tiny though.

Comment: Yeah, but it's pretty much like saying that pouring a glass of water in the ocean raises the water level. While it's technically true, it's also practically meaningless. (Google minimizes the CSS because it affects the loading time of the file.)

Comment: It not being significant is counter-intuitive to me. Selector-matching is an elaborate process since pretty much every DOM element has to be tested against every CSS selector.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Your computer also can make millions of calculations in a second. Whether it handles strings that have 20 characters or 3 characters doesn't make any visible difference.

Comment: @Juhana I *could* be under-estimating the computing power of CPUs haha

Comment: @Juhana have a look at my answer, and the JSPerf link in it. There does seem to be a quite measurable difference. If you are modifying the styles a huge amount of times, short class names do seem beneficial.

Comment: @Joeytje50 On my browser the difference is about 0.000000001 seconds per operation. This is not going to be a bottleneck, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't affect browser performance as much as it does loading times. There is a measurable difference in rendering time, but that is only measurable when there is a significant length difference, and even then it is a tiny difference. Just look at [**this JSPerf**](http://jsperf.com/long-vs-short-class) which runs a test for both class name lengths. The long names have a slight disadvantage in performance speed. This could make a difference when modifying styles a huge amount of times, but on normal sites, the difference is too small to ever be noticed.

Comment: How do you read this ? Is it with 100k classes ? What difference in seconds are we talking about ? And what about the transfer time ?

Comment: If you check out that link, you can run the performance test, which will show you that long class names take a slight bit longer to work with. The difference is definitely not in seconds, but milliseconds, or even less, but when testing this piece of javascript a couple thousand times, there is a slight difference. If that doesn't answer your question, I'm afraid I didn't understand your question. If so, could you rephrase the question please?

Comment: When I ran the test, the long class names were faster by a tiny amount. [See Results](http://i.imgur.com/pIzGWzj.png). Probably safe to conclude that such perf tests are meaningless ?